# Почему условия продолжается на первом пункте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Делаю тут бота для телеграм и столкнулся с проблемой. Когда функция ловит сообщение от пользователя он должен сравнить сообщение в условиях и выбрать нужную функцию, но почему то независимо от текста сообщения все равно будет выполнятся первое условие. вот мой код:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def weather(msg: types.Message):
    print('jdnjcndj')
    print(msg.text)
    if msg.text == "Погода сегодня" or "Weather today":
        print('njndcj')
        await weather_prognoz(msg.from_user.id, 'today')
    elif msg.text == "Прогноз на завтра" or "Forecast for tomorrow":
        print('sdjcsdkcjsdvk')
        await weather_prognoz(msg.from_user.id, 'tomorrow')
```

Comment: if msg.text == "Погода сегодня" or msg.text == "Weather today" и в elif тоже надо msg.text ==. А лучше if msg.text in [ "Погода сегодня" , "Weather today"]:

Comment: спасибо, помогло